# Retrieving values from multiple lists with Firebase in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a simple app listing a set of locations where a logged in user can mark a given location as "favorite".

My datastructure in firebase contains a simple list of locations as:

**Locations => location id: [] => [{name: "MyName"}, {name: "MyName 2}]**

**Likes => userId: [] => location id: [] => {liked: true}**

I want to iterate over this in my template using some simple logic:

```
  <md-card *ngFor="let location of locations | async">
    <md-card-title> {{location.name}}</md-card-title>
    <md-card-content>{{location.liked}}</md-card-content>
  </mc-card>
```

With the following logic from in my component

```
  locations: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    private cardService: CardService,
    private router: Router,
    public af: AngularFire)
  {
    this.locations = af.database.list('/trips')
      .map((locations) => {
        return locations.map((location) => {
          location.liked =  af.database.object(`/likes/${this.uid}/${location.$key}`);
          return location;
        })
      });
```

However, the location.liked property remains empty in my view. I checked that the /likes/${this.uid}/${location.$key} URL actually contains the desired data.

Any ideas on how I should handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `location.like` is firebase `database.object` which returns `FirebaseObjectObservable` object. To show object value on view, you should use `async` pipe over it

```
<md-card-content>{{location.liked | async}}</md-card-content>
```

You could find the same thing explained here in [**AngularFire Docs**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/2-retrieving-data-as-objects.md#retrieve-data)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.

To get the actual value from the object I had to use 

{{  location.liked | async).value }}

Comment: @user3642173 just be little careful by having `?.`(Elvis operator) like `{{ location.liked | async)?.value }}`

Comment: Thanks Pankaj - could you elaborate on why I should be careful with this?